# Populating a table using entity framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I'm using a MySQL database as a data source, and WPF to develop my app. I just decided to try out the entity framework 6 for the first time.

Naturally I'd look for some relative tutorials and start off with [this one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html). It required me to use the default 'World' database examples which come with the MySQL installation

I failed to get it work. I suspect mostly because since it's win forms based so I found [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg610409.aspx) which was WPF based, however, was not really made with a MySQL database in mind. I decided to keep using the MySQL examples as they seemed very similar to the ones used in the example. How ever when I ran it (@ Figure 6. Section in second tutourial), there was no population of any sort.

All I'm trying to do is populate a data grid and even that's eluding me. I only know how to do it with connection strings and queries written in the code behind.

Speaking of which, I decided to take a look at the code behind  and found this annotation right after the constructor:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource worldEntitiesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("worldEntitiesViewSource")));
    // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
    // worldEntitiesViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
}
```

I can't figure out how to make use of it though. Can anyone shed a bit of light on this for me? How would populate a datagrid in WPF using a MySQL Table?

Comment: Your question is off topic for this website because *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: @Sheridan - Edited to meet your requirements.

Comment: You still have this in your question: *My question is; is there any valid tutourial that describes how to use the entity framework with MySQL?* As my comment says, that is *still* off topic for this website. To be clear, this is *not* my requirement, it is taken from the Stack Overflow Help Center and is part of the guidelines that keeps this website running so well.

Comment: @Sheridan - Not to argue semantics but 'Your' was plural. You being a moderator would make you part of the stackoverflow administrative body. Your = stackoverflow. Edited again though. Not that it matters, clearly I'm on my own on this one.

Comment: As you have edited your question to make it on topic, I have now removed my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial:
 http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/426790/Using-MySQL-with-Entity-Framework
or maybe here can be something interesting for you:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mssmallbiz/archive/2014/07/07/largest-collection-of-free-microsoft-ebooks-ever-including-windows-8-1-windows-8-windows-7-office-2013-office-365-office-2010-sharepoint-2013-dynamics-crm-powershell-exchange-server-lync-2013-system-center-azure-cloud-sql.aspx